# Tests fail with custom jsr validators with @Inject for Spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, junit4, bean-validation, jhipster

**Versions**

1. hibernate-validator - 5.1.3.Final
2. spring-boot - 1.2.5.RELEASE
3. spring-context - 4.1.7.RELEASE

The initial application code was generated using jhipster.

The relevant controller tests are marked with following annotations.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest
```

The validator beans are not getting wired in test mode. Looks like the `ConstraintFactory` implementation used in web mode is `o.s.v.b.SpringConstraintValidatorFactory` while in test mode the implementation used is  `o.h.v.i.e.c.ConstraintValidatorFactoryImpl` which does not take care of processing @Inject annotations.

The web app uses MySQL as database while tests use H2.

How I do get the tests configured to use SpringConstraintValidatorFactory?

I've tried the following based on previous questions and solutions.

1. This is not a second validation done by Hibernate while saving entities. I've checked this by analyzing call stack. The validator is being triggered from web layer with @Valid annotation on a rest method.
2. Adding this to application.yml file is not helping. I am guessing that this is meant for hibernate save/update validation. In my case the validation at the web layer.

> spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.mode=none

Thanks.

Comment: Please explain -ve votes. I would like to fix any issue in this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in my case I had written couple of custom validators (following this https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html/validator-customconstraints.html) that required autowiring. I was providing the validator class in the @Constraint annotation like.

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = MyCheckValidator.class)
```

I saw that in the standard validators such @NotNull etc validatedBy was populated as a empty array.

In my validators, I changed validatedBy field to {} and it all started working. I dont know why.

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
```

Would be grateful if someone can explain the finer details.